Unable to pass the login screen ubuntu 23.10
I upgraded my pc from ubuntu 22.10 to 23.10. Everything went on well after restarting my pc, i couldn't go past the login screen. After many trials without success, i changed the display manager from gdm3 to lightdm and everything worked fine finally. i want to stick with gdm3 but am afraid it won't work again. Is there any way i can overcome this?
